# Login status not showing logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, forms-authentication, loginview

I have a website, in which a user Logs in. I am using an `asp:Login`. The login page works fine, but i have associated an event handler that when the user logs in the site will get redirected to an authentication page which will send the Username in this manner.

```
 protected void LoginUserPass_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Redirect("~/Authenticate.aspx?user=" + LoginUserPass.UserName);
        }
```

And the i have set the `DestinationPageUrl` of my LoginView to be `"~/Authenticate.aspx"`. Once the user is authenticated another Redirection to a members page occurs. However in my Members page it does not show that the user is logged in.

```
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
        LogoutAction="Redirect" BackColor="White" 
        Font-Underline="True" LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the user logs in the site will get redirected...

If the user is logging in with a username and password, then you redirect, your user is not logged in before the redirect on the `LogginIn` event:

[Login.LoggingIn Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggingin.aspx)

> The **LoggingIn** event is raised when a user submits login information but before the user is authenticated on the Web site. Use the LoggingIn event to set up any information that you need before authenticating a user.

Use LoggedIn instead:

[Login.LoggedIn Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx)

> The **LoggedIn** event is raised after the authentication provider checks the user's credentials and the authentication cookie is queued to send to the browser in the next response. Use the LoggedIn event to provide additional processing, such as accessing per-user data, after the user is authenticated.